# Set TLS SSL version 1.2 on azure container instance

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

Please how do I set azure container instance to use TLS 1.2 and not TLS 1.0 and 1.1

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-web-service) yet it installed TLS 1.0 and 1.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The link you shared is point to Azure Machine Learning not ACI. You can secure you ACI containers with TLS 1.2 by either setting up an App Gateway or using an Nginx side car. Please follow these links for further reference:

1. [Expose static IP with App Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway) and [Enable TLS 1.2 in AG](https://hardeepbhamra.com/azure-enable-tls-1-2-in-application-gateway/)
2. [Enable a TLS endpoint in a sidecar container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl) and [Enable TLS1.2 on Nginx](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-nginx-to-use-only-tls-1-2-and-1-3/#Set_up_TLS_1.2_in_Nginx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Faheem. But how do I set the TLS to version TLS 1.2?  when deploying a machine learning model on a container instance. Using Azure ML workspace.

Comment: It should have created the deployment with TLS1.2. There is not such setting available through `AciWebservice.deploy_configuration`. What error are you getting?

Comment: Am not getting an error. But even after deploying with AciWebservice.deploy_configuration, it still includes TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.

Comment: I am afraid I don't see any knobs in their deployment API. However, if you deploy your own NGINX as a sidecar to handle the TLS termination then you will have the full control. I would get in touch with MS support to get further help.

Comment: Thank you Faheem